# Tracing code that leads to SVG error in chrome

Tags: svg, d3.js, google-chrome-devtools

An error `Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute x="NaN"` creeped into my code, or rather I should say, is being raised by the browser while running my code, and I am not sure how to trace it back to my javascript code.

On the chrome console, I only get the aforementioned error text, and a quite useless reference to my html file's first line. My SVG elements are all being created by my javascript (d3.js) code in this case, therefore I am unable to trace back from this error to my code.

I would almost as easily trace back to my code if I at least knew which SVG element this error refers to. Getting a stack trace for this error would be more elegant, of course.

Any ideas?

Comment: as an aside, this seems to imply that d3 does not perform any sanity checking on values it passes on to the DOM - no surprise there, but is there any way to make it catch the error before it reaches the DOM, in some sort of debug mode?

Comment: The line number you get for the error should point you to the code that causes it. There, you're setting an `x` attribute for an `svg` element. The code that's run for this returns a `NaN`.

Comment: That's obvious Lars, but I have no code that defines or manipulates svg inside my html. The code that creates and manipulates SVG is all javascript, which is not in the html file. I am really talking about tracing back to code (or to the relevant SVG element) in this question.

Comment: Without the error message and some code I can't help you there. You would usually get some kind of stacktrace in Chrome that pinpoints the source of the error.

Comment: No, there's no stack trace, otherwise there'd be no issue.

Comment: That was the whole point - figuring out how to get around not getting a stack trace!